# How to prettify this chemfig figure?

Tags: chemfig

I would like to create a figure of dipeptide condensation of two [amino acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid):

I was looking at the chemfig [manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) and came up with the following solution:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setchemfig{atom sep=2.2em}
    \setchemfig{arrow offset=3pt,arrow coeff=0.7} 
    \schemestart
        \chemname{\chemfig{N(-[:120]H)(-[:-120]H)-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]\color{orange}{R_1})-\color{red}{C}(=[:60]\color{red}{O})(-[:-60]\color{blue}{OH})}}{Amino acid 1}
        \+
        \chemname{\chemfig{\color{red}{N}(-[:120]\color{red}{H})(-[:-120]\color{blue}{H})-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]\color{violet}{R_2})-C(=[:60]O)(-[:-60]OH)}}{Amino acid 2}
        \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
        \chemname{\chemfig{N(-[:120]H)(-[:-120]H)-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]\color{orange}{R_1})-[:-30]\color{red}{C}(=[:-90]\color{red}{O})-[:+30]\color{red}{N}(-[:90]\color{red}{H})-[:-30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]\color{violet}{R_2})-[:+30]C(=[:60]O)(-[:-60]OH)}}{Dipeptide}
        \+
        \chemname{\chemfig{\color{blue}{H_2O}}}{Water}
        \schemestop
    \chemnameinit{}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

How can I make it more appealing and align the elements and the labels better?

Comment: have a look a this answer -- the same can be edited to meet your requirement -- please revert  --https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553958/197451

Comment: Be more specific, *"more attractive"* is relative and can be interpreted differently by different people. Say exactly what you want to achieve, if necessary by adding a freehand drawing of the desired result.

Comment: @AndréC I just want the LHS and the RHS to align better with each other, but I am not opposing to any other improvements.

Comment: I'm not a chemist and I don't know what LHS and RHS is.

Comment: @AndréC left hand side, right hand side of the arrow.

Comment: It looks well aligned to me, what do you think is the problem here?